# Reading tracert output - what does this address mean?

Tags: ip, hostname, networking

```
  7     7 ms     2 ms     3 ms  83.149.18.148 
  8     *       78 ms     *     ae52.edge7.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [195.16.162.53] 
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10    80 ms    80 ms    80 ms  xe-10-0-1.fra44.ip4.tinet.net [141.136.102.69] 
 11   235 ms   235 ms   238 ms  xe-9-3-0.lax20.ip4.tinet.net [89.149.182.17] 
 12   234 ms   233 ms   233 ms  giglinx-gw.ip4.tinet.net [173.241.129.78] 
 13   240 ms   233 ms   235 ms  xe-2-1-0-0.laxcs1-4.blacklotus.net [192.184.8.69] 
 14   235 ms   235 ms   235 ms  192.31.186.3 

Trace complete.
```

Okay I have this tracert, for example. How to get know what exactly means `xe-9-3-.lax20.ip4.tinet.net`? It's just some machinery address that doesn't say to me anything. I know how to resolve it to IP, but how to know what it means, whom it belongs (I need this to realize on which side is there a network problem)? My goal is to know why I can't access some URL.

Comment: The problem, if there is one, is not there at the line you've indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine name is largely arbitrary and irrelevant to your quest in working why you can't access a particular domian name.

In this case we can make an educated guess that the domain is going through a server belonging to "tinet.net" in Los Angeles.  The IPv4 implies their network may have different routers for IPv4 and IPv6 (which may or may not be true)  The xe-9-3-0 is probably only meaningful to someone who works there.

Your traceroute gives no indication that the problem has anything to do with this machine - the increase in latency from the previous hop is simply because of the distances between the hosts.

If you are trying to look at problems accessing the URL, it may pay to focus on MTU issues, firewall and server issues rather then traceroutes - at least once a traceroute or ping has confirmed end-to-end connectivity as this one does.

Comment: thx. Seems like it's the answer I needed. -)

Comment: Most likely, `lax20` is the router's identifier, `xe` is the interface type, and `9-3-0` means something like slot 9, module 3, port 0.